# How to update state that has dependency on other state with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I have this custom hook:

```
import sortBy from 'lodash/fp/sortBy';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

/**
 * Custom effect that enables data sorting.
 * It is triggered every time when sort order or data has changed.
 *
 * @param {*} initialSort
 * @param {*} data
 */
function useSorting(initialSort, data) {
  const [sortOrder, setSortOrder] = useState(initialSort);
  const [sortedData, setSortedData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => setSortedData(sortBy(sortOrder, data)), [data, sortOrder]);

  return [sortedData, sortOrder, setSortOrder];
}

export default useSorting;
```

It accepts data to be sorted and sort order. Each time sort order is changed via `setSortOrder` or new `data` is provided, it should do the sorting and update `sortedData`.

Is this the correct way? I mean, to have a `useEffect` that is listening for changes in `[data, sortOrder]`?

Without React hooks I would use `componentDidUpdate` and manually check if `sortOrder` or `data` was changed and do `this.setState` with new `sortedData`. It looks like it does a similar thing

Answer (score 2):

Your example should work, and this is what happens in order, say when you pass new `data` or you use `setSortOrder`.

1 - You arrive inside the code of your hook

2 - You hook uses `setSortedData` to update it's `sortedData` state

3 - It returns a stale `sortedData` to your component (because it was read from `useState` before being modified)

4 - The call to `setSortedData` kicks in, changes the data in the state, triggers a new render of your component, which will use your hook again, and the hook will provide the right version of `sortedData`.

In a nutshell, you have one extra render. If you want to prevent that, you could use `useMemo`, like so:

```js
function useSorting(initialSort, data) {
  const [sortOrder, setSortOrder] = useState(initialSort);
  const sortedData = useMemo(() => sortBy(sortOrder, data), [data, sortOrder]);

  return [sortedData, sortOrder, setSortOrder];
}
```

Your component will get the sorted data right away without having to go through an extra rendering loop, and you still have the benefits of having your sorting function called only if relevant information change (`data`, `sortOrder`).

Comment: Exactly, I was concerned about one extra render. Thanks